# List USB device and choose one as backup batch file

Tags: list, batch-file, usb, usb-drive

so i'm writing a little batch file that does several useful things, but i am having trouble with one in specific, i am using this command:

`set /p choice="Press Enter to show available Backup USB Drives" 
if "%choice%"=="" wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get deviceid, volumename,`

which works and it displays available usb devices, but from those devices i'd like to create a list so the user can choose what drive to use as a backup drive, any help is much appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any USB drives to plugin to see what the output of that WMIC command is.  Could you edit your question to show the output from the command.  Thanks.

Comment: the output is: Description:Removable Disk  DeviceID:E: VolumeName:CORSAIR

Answer (score 0):

This will display all the avaiable drive and test if the answer is a valid drive (present in the List) :

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Creating a list with all USB drive

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=2 get deviceid ^| find ":"') do set "$List=!$List! %%a"

::Your Menu

:menu
set /p choice="Press Enter to show available Backup USB Drives" 
if "%choice%"=="" goto:USB
goto:menu

exit/b

::Displaying available drive and asking to choose one

:USB  
echo Avaiable Drive ==^> !$List!
set /p "$Drive=Enter the letter of the Backup drive : "
cls

::Testing the availibility of the choosed drive in the List

echo !$List! | find /i "%$Drive::=%:" && Echo drive OK || Echo drive do not exist && goto:USB
```

In place of the `Echo drive OK` you can make a `Goto:next` and use `!$Drive!` as choosed drive.

Comment: The script provided shows only 2 devices, if i have more than 2 devices they won't show, how can i modify it to show all usb devices?

Answer (score -1):

:-) i created a variable that the user inputs, instead of choosing from an actual list, the user just types in the drive letter, e.g: G: i realized that even if i make an actual list, the user still has to type in the drive he wants to use, so why not use the typed drive letter as a variable and add it to the xcopy command line, here's the whole code for the little utility, i'll add a little folder tree later on to select a backup source better than just typing it in manually

```
`@echo off
:: variables
set backupcmd=xcopy /w /S /D /E /H /I /R /-Y
:start
echo =====================
echo   Backup Utility
echo =====================
echo.
set /p sourcepath=  Enter Folder or Drive path to be Copied:
echo.
ECHO =======================================================
echo Backup Source Path: %sourcepath%
ECHO =======================================================
echo.
set /p choice="Press Enter to show available Backup USB Drives"
ECHO ======================================================= 
echo.
if "%choice%"=="" wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get deviceid,       
volumename, description
echo.
ECHO =======================================================
echo.
ECHO =======================================================
set /p backuppath= Enter Backup Destination, Use DeviceID (e.g: E:):
echo You selected %backuppath% as your Backup destination 
ECHO =======================================================
echo.
echo =======================================================
echo.
echo Backup Sourcepath Selected=  %sourcepath%
echo Backup Destination Selected= %backuppath%
echo.
echo========================================================
ECHO.
set /p choice="If it looks good, Press Enter to Continue, or 0 to Start   
Over: " 
ECHO.
if "%choice%"=="" goto Backup Files
if "%choice%"=="0" goto start
pause

:Backup Files
echo =========== Ready to Back up your Files ===========
ECHO.
%backupcmd% "%sourcepath%" "%backuppath%"
ECHO.
echo Success!!
echo Finished at:
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%a-%%b-%%c)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a:%%b)
echo %mytime% %mydate%
start %backuppath%
echo =====================================================
echo.
goto start`
```

Comment: Like this you don't have any control of the existing USB drive. To test if the user Enter an existing one. Programmatically this is a very bad solution. You have a complete working solution instead.